# Save a javascript object in an HTML object

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to save a javascript tag in an HTML object? What I would like to do is something like this:

```
<div id="htmlTag">some text</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    htmlTag.something = {s:"a string",n:1,b:false,a:[3,2,1],f:function(){alert("hello")}}
</script>
```

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: There's no such thing as an "HTML object."

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I would like to save javascript information related to the HTML object but that doesn't concern it directly.

Comment: @DonaldDuck What do you mean by "but that doesn't concern it directly"?

Comment: @guest271314 If it doesn't exist the HTML object will work and look exactly the same as if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your only problem is you're not getting the node.

```
document.getElementById("htmlObject").something = {hi: 1};
```

Comment: that said, I can't imagine a good use case for this unless you're developing some sort of html/js framework.

Comment: That doesn't work in old versions of IE and I would like my HTML to be compatible with them.

Comment: then use `document.getElementById("htmlObject")`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert JS objects to JSON string with [this plugin](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), if that is what you want to achieve.

```
var json_data = JSON.stringify(yourObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the javascript function [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

**Javascript**

```
<div id="htmlTag">some text</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('htmlTag').something = JSON.stringify({s:"a string",n:1,b:false,a:[3,2,1],f:function(){alert("hello")}});
</script>
```

Here is a JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/LcrLeg8a/1/

Comment: You actually don't need to stringify. Node elements are treated similar to regular js objects, so you can add arbitrary properties to it.